# Sequelize m:n relation: Access association in beforeHook

Tags: javascript, mysql, sequelize.js

So in Sequelize I have two models `ModelA` and `ModelB` that have many to many relation between them. Then I call `instanceA.createModelB()` to create instance of ModelB and associate it with instanceA. Now I have a `beforeCreate` hook on ModelB, like this:

```
beforeCreate(instance, options) {
  return instance.countA().then(associations => {
     console.log(associations);
  })
}
```

It returns 0, because the relation between instanceA and instanceB is created only after all hooks were run.

I need to do some checks related to instanceA before I can create instanceB. Can I somewhow access the relation in the hooks, as that would be the best place to perform the checks? I know I can do it everytime before calling `instanceA.createModelB()` but I call it in many differnt places so I would like to do it in a more centralized way.

Comment: You have a typo `intance`. The `beforeCreate()` hook runs before an `instance` is created, but the associations should be defined beforehand as part of the `Model`, so I think your assumptions about the problem are incorrect.

Comment: The association is of course defined on the model, but the actual relation between two instances (the row in the relation table in DB) is created only after all hooks are finished.